# How to call a method on UIButton in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm trying to enable a button but the button that I would enable in this function changes. I have an array of the buttons but when I use the .enabled on the array index I want it says that this doesn't work for IDs.

I have used this array to set the text of each button before using:

```
[[ButtonArray objectAtIndex: Index] setTitle:(@"blahblahblah") forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

is there any way to use a similar function call to enable and disable?

Comment: Side Note - Class names begin with capital letters. Variables and method names should begin with lowercase letters. It's a standard convention used by many (most?) developers.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure that everything in that array is a `UIButton` you can cast it to make the compiler happy:

```
[(UIButton *)[ButtonArray objectAtIndex: Index] setTitle:(@"blahblahblah") forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: ok, but what I want is to change the button to enabled, I know that it worksks for setTitle.

Comment: It doesn't matter which `UIButton` method you call, if the problem is that you're being told "this doesn't work for IDs", casting will get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to split code up into multiple lines. It makes it easier to read, debug, and maintain.

```
UIButton *button = ButtonArray[Index]; // new, modern array syntax
button.enabled = YES;
[button setTitle:@"blah" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem was actually that I was setting enabled to NO when I wanted YES, I feel so stupid.